# Computing the MD5 checksum of a string

Tags: md5, sml

How do I compute the MD5 checksum of a string in Standard ML?

What I'd like is preferrably a function `md5 : string -> string`.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no MD5 checksum function in the standard library, use one of the following libraries found online.

- [md5.sml](https://sourceforge.net/p/tom7misc/svn/HEAD/tree/trunk/sml-lib/crypt/MD5/md5.sml?force=True) (Tom 7's public domain implementation from 2001):

  ```
  - MD5.bintohex (MD5.md5 "Hello World!")
  val it = "ED076287532E86365E841E92BFC50D8C" : string
  ```
- [md5.sml](https://github.com/MLton/mlton/blob/master/benchmark/tests/md5.sml) (Daniel Wang's implementation from 2001 found in MLton's tests):

  ```
  - MD5.toHexString (MD5.final (MD5.update (MD5.init, Byte.stringToBytes "Hello World!")))
  > val it = "ed076287532e86365e841e92bfc50d8c" : string
  ```